# How can I find the original bag listing for 42083 Bugatti Chiron?

Tags: organisation, set-database

I'm buying a used set (42083 Bugatti Chiron to be specific) and I would like to sort the parts in their original module bags. However, I can only find the complete part list, not the parts per module. Does anyone have a pointer as to how to retrieve the original sorting?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no such resource on the internet.
It's asked from time to time on other fora and groups I frequent, mainly from people who have a collection of bags and want to gather entire sets.
The best that can be done to get the parts per module is disassembling the set in reverse order of the instructions...